# Configuring VSCODE to debug JAVA - CORDOVA

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, visual-studio-code, cordova-plugins

I have successfully configured the `launch.json` file in a cordova project in order to debug / step through JAVA programs (though it isn't perfect).

First thing I did was install the language tool for java extension.

then I updated the paths in the `.vscode/launch.json`

{
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "type": "android",
                "name": "Android Debug",
                "request": "launch",
                "appSrcRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/platforms/android",
                "apkFile": "${workspaceRoot}/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk",
                "adbPort": 5037
            }
        ]
    }

then I modified the `AndroidManifest.xml` to change `android:name="MainActivity"` to read `android:name=".MainActivity"` in the following tag:

```
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

From there I was able to step-through my own code in the `VSCODE` debugger.

The problem I am still having is in the OUTPUT window. I'm getting repeated errors:

On first load of the project I get this 3 or 4 times:

```
[Error - 9:39:52 AM] Jun 9, 2017 9:39:13 AM Synchronize Gradle projects with workspace failed due to an error configuring Eclipse.
    Can't read root project location for project located at C:\www\pdf-generator-example\platforms\android
    org.eclipse.buildship.core.GradlePluginsRuntimeException: Can't read root project location for project located at C:\www\pdf-generator-example\platforms\android
        at org.eclipse.buildship.core.configuration.internal.BuildConfigurationPersistence.readPathToRoot(BuildConfigurationPersistence.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.buildship.core.configuration.internal.DefaultConfigurationManager.loadProjectConfiguration(DefaultConfigurationManager.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation$3.apply(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:157)
        at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation$3.apply(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:153)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$6.computeNext(Iterators.java:617)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:145)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:140)
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:267)
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:229)
        at com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable.toList(FluentIterable.java:609)
        at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.getOpenWorkspaceProjectsRemovedFromGradleBuild(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:161)
        at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.synchronizeProjectsWithWorkspace(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.run(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:115)
        at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.synchronizeBuild(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.runToolingApiJob(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob$1.run(ToolingApiJob.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiInvoker.invoke(ToolingApiInvoker.java:62)
        at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob.run(ToolingApiJob.java:70)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

then this one "frequently" maybe once or twice a minute:

```
[Error - 9:40:28 AM] Jun 9, 2017 9:39:13 AM An internal error occurred during: "Update project android".
Can't read root project location for project located at C:\www\pdf-generator-example\platforms\android
org.eclipse.buildship.core.GradlePluginsRuntimeException: Can't read root project location for project located at C:\www\pdf-generator-example\platforms\android
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.configuration.internal.BuildConfigurationPersistence.readPathToRoot(BuildConfigurationPersistence.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.configuration.internal.DefaultConfigurationManager.loadProjectConfiguration(DefaultConfigurationManager.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultGradleWorkspaceManager.getGradleBuild(DefaultGradleWorkspaceManager.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.managers.GradleBuildSupport.update(GradleBuildSupport.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.managers.ProjectsManager$1.runInWorkspace(ProjectsManager.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

Other solutions I've seen on stackoverflow give instructions for how to fix this using commands in the eclipse IDE (select this menu, re-add the project, click this and that and it is fixed my the 'magic' of the IDE)

I'm wondering if anyone knows what is happening here "UNDER THE HOOD" enough that I might fix this without using IDE tricks in eclipse (since I don't have that installed)

If you're looking for a project to work with please feel free to look at:  https://github.com/AlexChesser/pdf-generator-example I'm currently contributing to the plugin functionality and would like to streamline my VSCODE config.